# aspire one laptop not booting from USB

Tags: ubuntu, usb, acer-aspire-one

I have an aspire one 756-4890 which i'm trying to boot from a bootable USB (ubuntu) which is not working correctly. Even in the boot option menu, i see just one option which says "Windows Boot Manager (ST5....142)".

Any ideas on how we can boot from USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off secure boot, and maybe change from UEFI to CSM / Legacy boot.

Unless you have made the Ubuntu to be UEFI capable boot, then you most likely need to move it to CSM/Legacy boot. (and that is assuming Secure Boot is off - and only then you may see the option of CSM/Legacy Boot)